# Setting up load balancing on 3 apache servers

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, load-balancing

I want to set up load balancing on my 3 Apache servers that I have created.

The 3 addressed that I have used for the server are, `192.168.151.101`, `.102` and `.103`

I have then created a load balance server and gave this an address of `192.168.151.105`

In the load balance server I have made the following file and gave it the following configuration

```
$ vi /etc/apache2/conf.d/proxy-balancer

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.101
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.102
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.103
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
```

I then need to configure our proxy to allow access from all hosts:

`$ vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf`

I then read online that you need to

> "Change the line “Deny from all” in this file to “Allow from all”.
>   Then restart Apache:"

However, I don't have a `Deny all` line to begin with so I am unsure what I am supposed to actually change to allow access from all hosts.

So does anybody know if I am supposed to change in this config file, or does anybody have an alternative method to do the load balancing?

Note: I have enabled all of the proxy modules

Answer (score 0):

Following apache recommendations (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), if your apache only works as ReverseProxy you must configure this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
# Then the config you actually have
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.101
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.102
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.103
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
```

The `Deny from all`line normally is for the Proxy when you use it for your user's navigation, not for ReverseProxy (which is your case)

Comment: So what do I actually need to do? Im sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: With the lines included in my answer should be enough. Perhaps later you will need some `ProxyPassReverse` if you have troubles with some redirections.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample after a real wold configuration that works for me

I had to use individual ProxyPassReverse directives to get redirections/links to work. Even the final / seems important.

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.101
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.102
BalancerMember http://192.168.151.103
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.151.101/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.151.102/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.151.103/
```